# docker container never comes up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

have a docker compose file with 2 containers to bring up. my current docker compose file looks like:

version: '3'

```
services:
  db:
    image: <image repo url>
    ports:
      - "5500:5500"

  web:
    image: <image repo url>
    ports:
     - "7001:7001"
```

I can see images are downloaded however doing a docker service ls shows:

```
vskumar-mac:~ vskumar$ docker service ls
ID            NAME                 MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE
8xpb4o1mqp3n  ora-tools-stack_db   replicated  1/1       imagerepo:5000/oradb:v1.1
lgqfpyspg9v0  ora-tools-stack_web  replicated  0/1       imagerepo:5000/orawls:v1.6
```

I have waited for hours to see if it comes up. but no luck.

Comment: Does it work in regular/non-swarm mode?

Comment: yes i can bring containers up individually without using the swarm mode.

Answer (score 0):

to check if container is up & running please type:

```
docker ps
```

Comment: no it is not docker ps -a shows just one container which is my db container.